# factory girl set up with sequelize adapter

Tags: sequelize.js, factory-bot

**What Am I doing**

I am using factory girl with sequelize adapter for testing with Mocha. I know I am doing something wrong with the set up but could not pick up the problem.

Here is my code:

modal:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Region = sequelize.define("Region", {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    open: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    }
  });
  Region.associate = models => {
    Region.hasMany(models.Area, {
      foreignKey: "regionId",
      as: "areas"
    });
  };
  return Region;
};
```

Factory:

```
var factory = require("factory-girl");
const adapter = new factory.SequelizeAdapter();
factory = factory.factory;
factory.setAdapter(adapter);

const Region = require("../../src/models/region");

factory.define("region", Region, () => {
  return {
    name: factory.chance("first"),
    open: "true",
    description: factory.chance("sentence", { words: 5 })
  };
});
```

index file for factory:

```
import factory from "factory-girl";

import "./regions";
import "./areas";

global.factory = factory;

export default factory;
```

My Mocha testing file:

```
import chai from "chai";
import assert from "assert";
import app from "../../src/app";
import chaiHttp from "chai-http";
import factories from "../factories";
// import dotenv from "dotenv";
// dotenv.config({path: ".env.test"});
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe("'regions'service", () => {
  it("should POST area", async () => {
    const region = await factories.create("region");
    const dummy = {
      name: "New area",
      open: true,
      description: "This is a cool area!",
      gps: "122.123, 123.4123",
      regionId: region.dataValues.id
    };
    const res = await chai
      .request(app)
      .post("/api/areas")
      .send(dummy);
    console.log(res.body);
    assert.equal(res.body.name, dummy.name);
  });
});
```

** What error do I get **

> TypeError: Model.build is not a function

So I get this is something to do with Model is not returning as a constructor. But how do I make it return a constructor?

If I change the require method in the factory as following:

```
var factory = require("factory-girl");
const adapter = new factory.SequelizeAdapter();
factory = factory.factory;
factory.setAdapter(adapter);
const sequelize = require("sequelize");
const DataTypes = sequelize.DataTypes;

const Region = require("../../src/models/region")(sequelize, DataTypes);

factory.define("region", Region, () => {
  return {
    name: factory.chance("first"),
    open: "true",
    description: factory.chance("sentence", { words: 5 })
  };
});
```

Then I get the error `factory.define` is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish this was made more clear... but when you `define` a factory, a FUNCTION CONSTRUCTOR needs to be passed in.

```
const Region = require("../../src/models").Region;
```

This would be be way to do it if you define the model listed above. But the key is I need to pass in constructor for the model.